How to find which `AudioHardwareControl` is related to input or output?
A long-overdue Core Audio API in pure Swift was silently introduced in macOS Sequoia. Now you can easily get the default output device and even all available controls of that device without resorting to unsafe pointers. However I didn't found a way to find which controls related to input and which to output:
let system = AudioHardwareSystem.shared
guard let defaultOutputDevice = try system.defaultOutputDevice else { return }
let allControls = try defaultOutputDevice.controls
let volumeControls = allControls.filter { (try? $0.classID) == kAudioVolumeControlClassID }
print(volumeControls) // 2 volume controls, input + output, but which is which?

One can always resort to the old way, like:
let system = AudioHardwareSystem.shared
guard let defaultOutputDevice = try system.defaultOutputDevice else { return }
let address = AudioObjectPropertyAddress(mSelector: kAudioHardwareServiceDeviceProperty_VirtualMainVolume,
                                         mScope: kAudioDevicePropertyScopeOutput,
                                         mElement: kAudioObjectPropertyElementMain)
guard defaultOutputDevice.hasProperty(address: address) else { return }
let data = try defaultOutputDevice.propertyData(address: address)
let volume = data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: Float32.self) }

But is there any way to figure out which AudioHardwareControl is related to input and which to output?

Are you sure those controls aren't both output? e.g. maybe you're using something like AirPods, which have both left and right volume controls. What do the controls' name and modelName report?

@GordonChilds This is a USB mic with a mini-jack output built in, so it should have two volume controls. Both name and modelName throws The AudioObject doesn't know about the property at the given address for both controls.
